# val.foreach is not a function after it reaches the key.length 2 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a matchmaking system where players with less than or greater than equal 15 weight, will be matched.

> `For example Player 105 has 2185 and player 132 has 2000. They'll be matched.`

This is my example data from console log when they're matched.

```
2185_2200: Array(2)
0: {entryID: '105', eventID: '22', …}
1: {entryID: '132', eventID: '22',  …}
length: 2
```

Now, my problem is i have also a no match players, and they're displayed like this:

[image]

Is there a way where i can console.log only those data with ARRAY(2)? and ignore those players without a match?

[image]

My foreach doesn't do an error when my no-matched players are only `9`, but when it reaches `10`, I'm getting an val.Foreach is not a function. I think I am missing another condition in my script. I hope you can help me, I'm stucked here for days. Thank you in advance and appreciate you

html:

```
//I am appending my result here
  <div id="resulta">
             
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function newCombine(data, difference) {

  let nonMatched = [...data]
  const groups = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < nonMatched.length - 1; i++) {
    const first = nonMatched[i]

    inner: for (let j = nonMatched.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
      const second = nonMatched[j]
      const delta = Math.abs(first.weight - second.weight)

      if (delta <= difference && first.entryName !== second.entryName) {
        const groupKey = `${first.weight}_${second.weight}`
        groups[groupKey] = [first, second]
        nonMatched = nonMatched.filter(
          obj => obj.entryID != first.entryID && obj.entryID != second.entryID
        )
        i = -1
        break inner
      }
    }
  }
  return { ...groups, ...nonMatched }
}    



$(document).ready(function() {




let resulta = [];
var html = "";

var entry_list =$('#entry_list1').DataTable({ 
      
 
        "ajax": {
              "url": "<?php echo site_url('report/controlget')?>",
            "type": "get",
            
           success: function(data) {
                
             const source = data;
             
             
             const result = newCombine(source, 15);
                    console.log(result);
            
                var aaa = Object.entries(result)
                
            var a = Object.keys(aaa);
                
        
        
        a = a.map(o => {
                    return o.replace(/(_)/mg, '').replace(/(_)/mg, '');
            })

var int_number = 9;
var int_length = (''+int_number).length;
 console.log(int_length);

  var count = 0;  
            
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {


   aaa[a[i]].forEach(function(val ,index) {
    var asd = val.length;
    
   console.log(Array.val);    
if(asd == 2){ 


 

 val.forEach(function(value, index) { // // when the keys reached 2 digits (10 - 11 -12 or so on), my console will error with a message "val.forEach is not a function".
  
var idaa = value.eventID ; 
  



      var entryIDs = index == 0 ? "entryIDM[]" : "entryIDW[]"
      var players = index == 0 ? "playerM[]" : "playerW[]"
      var weights = index == 0 ? "weightM[]" : "weightW[]"
      var legBands = index == 0 ? "legBandM[]" : "legBandW[]"
      var wingBands = index == 0 ? "wingBandM[]" : "wingBandW[]"
      html += `<input type="text" name="${entryIDs}" value="${value.entryID}"> 
                 <input type="text" name="${players}" value="${value.entryName}">
                 <input type="text" name="${weights}" value="${value.weight}">
                 <input type="text" name="${legBands}" value="${value.legBand}">
                 <input type="text" name="${wingBands}" value="${value.wingBand}">
                 
                 <input type="text" name="eventID" value="${value.eventID}">
             
`

  })
 }  
    
   




  })
}



document.getElementById("resulta").innerHTML = html //add html to div


            },
            }
    
 
    });
    
 });
```

Comment: can you show what is the in console.log(val), when it fails?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Here's the result of console.log(val)

https://prnt.sc/20x6k0r

Comment: Hello @UlquiorraSchiffer Hope you are doing good Rain. Could you create a codepen example and share with me. Would like to understand your problem and give it a try after I complete my task. Busy right now

Comment: One advise from me though. I observed and noticed in your code that  you are mixing two syntax. Javascript and JQuery. [In only rare cases we should do that, in fact avoid that in most of the cases].

This is JavaScript, 
`document.getElementById("resulta").innerHTML`

But anything starting with `$()` is JQuery. 

Try to change all the code to JQuery. Because the way DOM objects are returned differ a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is already been solved. But i will improve my codes based on your suggestion. Thank you and appreciated.

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer You are most welcome. Glad to know that it is resolved. Keep it up ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Your Val is not an array it's an object so you cant use forEach.

```
Object.values(val).forEach // should work for you
```

Comment: I changed my codes to your mine. And it still error. Is there a way where I can remove these "no match" results from my console log? I don't need these to be honest. I just want to console.log my players with a match. I think the error occurs because of this  no match players. :/ :/

Comment: The val.foreach always saying error when the key length reaches 2 digits such as 10,11,12 and so on. Maybe i have a problem regarding my condition statement in script.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed return nonmatched... Now it only returns the matched players.

Thank you everyone.

```
return { ...groups}
```

Comment: Hey, Rain. Do visit my website(in my profile details on SO) to follow me on github and linkidln to discuss technology further as discussed. Thank you

Comment: I will. Thank you :D